# Does Glue bookmark rewind feature delete data from sink?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using Glue Bookmark feature and it seems to work correctly on source : only new files are processed.

I'm wondering if the rewind (or reset) feature is able to identify data that need to be updated at destination as well ?

Should I be using the same transformation_ctx value along the source and transformation to sink to enable that ?

The source is s3 through Catalog (JSON) and destination is s3 (Parquet), both with DynamicFrame libs

Comment: I replied to a similar question, check this one if it can helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548147/why-i-need-to-set-the-transformatioin-ctx-parameter-when-calling-transformation

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it does help !

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here : [Why I need to set the transformatioin_ctx parameter when calling transformation and sink operataions for AWS Glue bookmark to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548147/why-i-need-to-set-the-transformatioin-ctx-parameter-when-calling-transformation)

The bookmark feature is only used for identifying changes in the source (read function) and not in transformations or destination (write). Thus, the transformation context only make sense for read function at the moment (and from s3 only)