# Why do I need to set the `transformation_ctx` parameter when calling transformation and sink operations for AWS Glue bookmark to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

The AWS Glue Bookmark document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) seems to suggest one has to pass a `transformation_ctx` parameter to source, transform and sink operation for the bookmark to work. This is reflected in the sample code in that page, where invocation of all of `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog()`, `ApplyMapping.apply()` and `write_dynamic_frame.from_options()` are passed with a `transformation_ctx` value.

I can understand the point to pass such a `transformation_ctx` to `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog()` method, as AWS Glue needs to store the information about files which have been read in the bookmark under the given `transformation_ctx` key.

However, I don't understand why this is also necessary for methods like `ApplyMapping.apply()` and `write_dynamic_frame.from_options()`. To put it another way, what is the state information these operations need to store in the bookmark? If I don't pass `transformation_ctx` to these methods, what problems will this cause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same doubts about the bookmarking months ago (October 2019) and since the documentation provided by Amazon is not very clear I opened a support case to understand more how it is implemented.

In my Glue Job there was:

- A read function from S3 (glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options)
- A ResolveChoice.apply
- A write function to Redshift (glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf)

All of these operations has the transformation_ctx value, I tested different possible behaviours (same transformation_ctx for all, different, fixed values, dynamic values ecc).

After many message with the AWS support they confirm that the bookmarking works only on the read function (They also said with only S3 as a source but I didn't test it), so I ask if the transformation_ctx is useless in the ResolveChoice (and write function too) and they said YES! They confirmed that doesn't make any difference.

Futhermore for the write function it doesn't change anything, so there is no bookmark logic, no "avoid function" if it has been already run before.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Their document really needs some improvement ;). BTW. Could you elaborate what you mean by ' it only changes the output file's name'? Do you mean the s3 file name will be different depending on whether you pass the transformatino_ctx to the writer methods?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer I was wrong about the different name in output