# Creating a substring in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a data source in an S3 bucket. The data source is the CSV file with one column "ID". I want to use AWS Glue to complete an ETL job. I want to extract the data from the S3 bucket, create a second column ("ID Suffix") which is the last two elements of the "ID", and then load this data file into a different S3 bucket. So if the "ID" is 1000031, I want the second column to be 31.

Here is the script that AWS Glue created for the simple task of extracting the file from one S3 bucket and putting it into another. I would like to edit it to accomplish the task above.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "stackoverflow", table_name = "sample_data_csv", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "stackoverflow", table_name = "sample_data_csv", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("id", "int", "id", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("id", "int", "id", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://aws-glue-scripts-us-west-1/Sample data"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://aws-glue-scripts-us-west-1/Sample data"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

Comment: the concept of a substring is indeed a simple one, but to answer your question, we need to understand so much more about what you're doing now.  can you create a complete example with a data source of just the one column/row and the way you can access it completely without the substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use dataframe functions since they are much easier to understand and use. In your case you can transform your dynamic frame to dataframe and call simples pyspark function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

new_df = datasource0.toDF()\
           .withColumn("id_suffix",
                       F.substring(F.col("id"), F.length("id") - 2, 2)
```

And later convert back to dynamic frame

```
dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataframe=new_df, glue_ctx=my_glue_context, name="generic-name")
```

[Pyspark Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Furthermore, you don't need to setup the transformation context on every function, I already explained why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548147/why-do-i-need-to-set-the-transformation-ctx-parameter-when-calling-transformat/62556388#62556388)